# Where in the .NET Framework is Proxy pattern utilized

Tags: .net, design-patterns, proxy-pattern

I know Web Services and WCF services are examples of the proxy pattern, where else in .NET land is the proxy pattern utilized?

Comment: If you download the Enterprise Library Code and look at the source, there is likely plenty of proxy patterns utilized.  I can't get specific as my computer is having issues, but the Logger is somewhat of a proxy pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COM-Callable Wrappers (CCW) and Runtime-Callable Wrappers (RCW) are classic examples of the use of Proxies.  Likewise for .NET Remoting.